# Quel est le fils rouge ou le sens basal de « se faire » ?

Tags: sens, étymologie

Les [maintes acceptions de « se faire »](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/faire) m'embrouillent, car elles semblent manquer de rapport.

Plutôt qu’éplucher chaque sens à part, je m’enquiers de la vue d’ensemble,
(à savoir) de [l’acception basale, sous-jacente, fondamentale, et du fil rouge](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/underlying)
(de la même manière que [cette explication](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/24102/50720) profite de l’acception basale de ‘tally’).

Donc, quelle métaphore ou notion centrale recouvre, rapproche toutes les acceptions qui semblent différentes, et explique les changements sémantiques?

PS: Ma connaissance de l'étymon latine, *facere*, ne résout pas ma confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Se faire --> *Faire **à soi** quelque chose*.

Se faire --> *Faire **de soi** quelque chose*.

Mais 'soi' n'est pas forcément une personne :

- Se donner qqch. ou une qualité (Ce fromage se fait dans une cave)
- Gagner (Se faire des millions)
- S'attirer des personnes (Se faire des relations)
- Se bonifier, mûrir, devenir soi (Se faire tout seul)

... sont les principales possibilités qu'un premier regard trouve dans le dictionnaire, auquel il faudrait ajouter *se faire à* :

- S'habituer à, s'accoutumer (Se faire à un genre de vie).

---

En complément de la *[question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/14787/faire-une-id%C3%A9e-diff%C3%A8re-de-se-faire-une-id%C3%A9e)* :

*On ne fait pas* une idée, mais *on a* une ou des idées (qui arrivent comme les nuages dans le ciel, ou des poussières dans le vent selon certains penseurs).

De ce fait, on s'attribue cette idée, on construit quelque chose (un raisonnement, un sentiments, une émotion, une illusion) à partir d'une idée qui nous est venue à l'esprit.

*On s'en fait une idée*, c'est-à-dire que quelque chose à pris langue avec nos neurones et a déclenché le mental, trop content d'arriver pour organiser tout cela : cela peut être génial (l'idée de la Relativité par exemple), ou un magnifique plan sur la comète (Il *se fait des idées* celui-là, il n'est pas un peu mythomane ?).

---

*<sup>Exemples et synonymes extraits du petit Robert</sup>*