# « Faire une idée » diffère de « se faire une idée » ?

Tags: sens, expressions, verbes, verbes-pronominaux

Source: p 93, *L'Etranger* (Twentieth-Century French Texts) (1998, 3 Rev Sub ed) par Albert Camus, Ray Davison (Relecteur)

> Mais un matin, je me suis souvenu d’une photographie publiée
>   par les journaux à l’occasion d’une exécution retentissante.* En réalité, la machine était
>   posée à même le sol, le plus simplement du monde. Elle était beaucoup plus étroite que je
>   ne le pensais. C’était assez drôle que je ne m’en fusse pas avisé plus tôt. Cette machine
>   sur le cliché m’avait frappé par son aspect d’ouvrage de precision, fini et étincelant. On
>   **se fait** toujours des idées exagérées de ce qu’on ne connaît pas. Je devais constater au
>   contraire que tout était simple: la machine est au même niveau que l’homme qui marche
>   vers elle.

Qu'est-ce qui changerait si Camus avait employé **faire**, plutôt que **se faire** ? Y a-t-il des différences entre « **faire** une idée » et « **se faire** une idée » ?

PS: Cette question peut être provoquée par [ma confusion avec **se faire**](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/14786/1995).

Comment: Vous pouvez inclure votre question dans celle citée en lien et supprimer celle-ci ; j'ai complété ma réponse pour rendre cohérent ce qui est relatif à *se faire*.

Comment: Réponse ajoutée ici : http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/14789/pourquoi-se-a-percevoir-sont-ils-tout-n%C3%A9cessaires-pour-signifier

Answer (score 2):

"Faire une idée" ne se dit tout simplement pas; il s'agit d'une expression qui nécessite le verbe à sa forme pronominale. "Se faire des idées" se traduit par "to be fooling oneself".

"Se faire du mauvais sang" signifie "to worry", "se faire à ____" signifie "to get used to ____", etc. Aucune de ces expressions n'utilise "faire" sans le pronom.