# Pourquoi « se » + « a » + « percevoir » sont-ils tous nécessaires pour signifier « se rendre compte » ?

Tags: étymologie, syntaxe

> II.− Emploi pronom. [...] 
>   B.− Au fig., emploi intrans.
>   **S'apercevoir de qqc.** (fait, état d'une chose ...). **S'apercevoir que** (suivi de l'indicatif). Prendre conscience, se rendre compte (après un effort d'attention ou après quelque recherche)

Il me faut séparer ce verbe réflexif en trois morphèmes pour le différencier des synonymes:

> **S'apercevoir** ⟸ se + a + [percevoir](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=perceive&allowed_in_frame=0)

1. [Cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/8266/1995) montre que seulement «  s'apercevoir » signifie « se rendre compte », une unicité qui est à l'origine de l'intitulé de cette question. Que signifient « se » et «  a » ici ?
   Comment ces deux morphèmes ont-ils généré une autre acception avec «  percevoir » ?
2. Pourquoi les synonymes plus courts (par exemple, *percevoir*, *se percevoir*, *apercevoir*) ne signifient-ils pas « se rendre compte » ?

Je sais que l'anglais est germanique et le français est une langue romane, mais la syntaxe française m'apparaît étrange :

- « Je **m'** aperçois **de** P » ✓, littéralement en anglais : « I apperceive **myself** **of** P » ✘

Sachant que la traduction directe de l'anglais idiomatique paraît fausse à un francophone :

- « I perceive P » ✓, littéralement : « Je perçois P » ✘

Comment: J'ai du mal à comprendre où vous voulez en venir avec les phrase 3 et 4 ? Pouvez vous développer ?

Comment: @Random Certes. Je voudrais montrer la différence de syntaxe entre les deux langues, et donc voudrais les concilier. Mieux ?

Answer (score 1):

*Apercevoir* n'est pas un synonyme de *percevoir* (ce sont les sens qui perçoivent) dans sa première acception, mais de *discerner, entrevoir, repérer, découvrir, remarquer*<sup>1</sup> (synonymes qui marquent une prise de conscience de ce qui a été *perçu*).

*S'apercevoir*, c'est *constater, noter, remarquer* et donc *se rendre compte* : ce qui est *aperçu* devient particulièrement important, ce n'est pas une image ou une perception fugitive à peine *entr'aperçue*.

---

*Sur la comparaison franco anglaise :*

*Apperceive* se traduit par  *se rendre compte* (donc avec '*self' inclus quelque part dans *ap*.* ajouté devant *perceive*) selon *[Reverso](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/apperceive)*, et s'apercevoir c'est,  de l'autre côté de la Manche, *rendre compte à soi-même* comme expliqué ci-dessus.

Comment les Français et les Anglais qui n'ont jamais cessé de se battre au cours de l'histoire s'empruntent et déforment leur vocabulaire dans des grammaires pas vraiment compatibles... c'est une toute autre histoire... peut-être créer un nouveau site sur SE pour découvrir toutes les étrangetés qui finalement les rapprochent :) .

---

*<sup>Références extraites du petit Robert</sup>*